# Correct way of getting Android application name

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am using following code to get the App label displayed in Android menu

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
String appLabel = appInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();
```

While above code works in most of the cases, I realised that it fails with [Gesture Builder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/apps/GestureBuilder). The label returned for Gesture Builder is **com.android.gesture.builder** instead of **Gestures Builder**. Check the AndroidManifest.xml file, which reveals details like Application has no label, but a launcher activity has one.

Should I always be looking for launcher activity and then its label? What is the correct approach to find out App label?

Comment: It depends on what you are using this for. If you are creating a home screen-style launcher, apps don't matter -- launcher activities do. If you are creating a list of installed apps, then launcher activities don't matter (though if you wanted to substitute the launcher activity label if the app label came back as `a.java.style.package`, you could do that, I suppose).

Comment: Hey CommonsWare, Thanks for your reply. I agree to what you said. Just wanted to make sure that whether I was using incorrect APIs or is there any better approach to handle the scenario. I will definitely modify the solution as per the requirements.

Comment: No, AFAIK, you are going about things OK. System apps do not necessarily have application labels, that's all.